# Centering output on IPython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have a similar question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380168/center-output-plots-in-the-notebook). I have an IPython notebook, I'd like the output to have centered plots. I've copied the css file and everything as instructed in the above link, and, whilst the plots change style, they don't center on my screen.

Comment: Which IPython version do you use?

Comment: iPython 1.1.0, Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might come a bit late but maybe Google brings more people here looking for a solution.
We can style the output in the *custom.css* in the IPython profile and add the following:

**with (older) IPython**

```
.ui-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

After that you just have to reload the page in your browser.

The `ui-wrapper`-div contains the `ui-resizable`-image and can be aligned in its parent `output-subarea`. `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto` will center. The keyword `!important` is necessary to avoid inline style overriding by the notebook. As far as I know, using !important is not the nicest thing to do but here it does the job.

If you don't know where the IPython profile can be found, you can run this code:

```
%%bash 
ipython locate
```

Usually it is located at *~/.ipython*, where ~ is your home folder. The css file should be located at *~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css* and should be empty if you have not used it before.

**with Jupyter (4.1.0)**

The HTML output of notebooks and file locations have changed since my first post. But the general approach stays the same even though we do not require `!important` any longer:

Find and/or create a `custom.css` file. It should be located at `$USER/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` on *nix systems. If it does not exist, create it and restart your notebook server. This should give you a hint about where to look:

```
import jupyter_core
custom_css = jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_config_dir() + '/custom/custom.css'
print "File: %s" % custom_css
```

On Windows you have to replace `/` with `\\` I guess.

The element to center is the image in the `output_png` div.

```
.output_png img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This has been tested with Firefox 44.0.2 and Chrome 49.0.

[image: centered output]

**With Jupyter themes**

Additionally, there are some theming tools around. I have not tested neither

- [jupyter-themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) nor
- [jupyter-themer](https://github.com/transcranial/jupyter-themer)

myself but they might be helpful.

Comment: @ostrokach, you are probably right. Elements and class naming has changed quite a lot during the development of notebooks. I have updated my answer with the most recent solution. Sorry for the horribly late response!