# How to center matplotlib outputs in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

By default they are leftwise located. Is there any easy possibility to change the alignment or relative position of the figure? For example I want to have my plt plot located in the center of the jupyter output cell and not at the left-side. Something like `ax.set_align="center"` would be nice.

I tried following:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML as Center

Center(""" <style>
.output_png {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style> """)
```

But it is not affecting the output. I tested it in Jupyter notebook and JupyterLab. For example, if I test a simple plot:

```
plt.hist(np.random.normal(size=1000), density=True, bins=30)  
plt.show()
```

then the figure is plotted at left side.

Comment: https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-center-a-matplotlib-figure-in-a-Jupyter-notebook-/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center output (plots) in the notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380168/center-output-plots-in-the-notebook)

Comment: Nope. Doesnt work with newer Jupyter notebook versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Modify` the `style` of the current notebook by executing a code cell with:

```py
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
.output_png {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
""")
```

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = (30 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: OutputImage]

Your sample exam would look something like this.

[image: OutputImage1]