# Centering plots in Jupyter-Lab using R kernel

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I'm using Jupyter-lab with **R kernel** and I would like to know how to center the plots I make. Here is how it looks by default :

[image: Default display]

I would like to make it like this :

[image]

Comment: Seems like a feature request for https://github.com/IRkernel/repr

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do it with the IRdisplay package, like for Python with the Ipython.core.display package, cf this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380168/center-output-plots-in-the-notebook